# How do I suppress "Firebase iOS builds are not supported on Windows" error in Unity?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a mobile game and only want to use Firebase for Android push notifications (side note: if there's a better way than Google Firebase Cloud Messaging, let me know). I don't want to use it for iOS because I can't build from PC and you don't need it for basic push notifications on iOS anyway.

The problem is, when I load the Firebase SDK into Unity, I keep getting an error "Firebase iOS builds are not supported on Windows. Please build on a OSX machine instead."

It doesn't stop me from building the game, but it's very annoying and I'd like to not have any errors.

Is there a way to suppress this error, or some configuration I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the source, it looks like you should only see that issue if you're on Windows and your build target is iOS:

```
EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS && Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor
```

You should be able to avoid the error completely if you select Android as your build target before opening in Unity Hub:
[image: A picture of Unity hub. The "Target" for the "FireKing" project is open with "Android" being visible]

You can also change to Android in your build settings window:
[image: Build setting window open with Android set as the platform target]

This setting should be sticky, so you should only have to do it once (unless you switch back to iOS).

If this is not possible, you can also try setting your platform to "PC, Mac, & Linux Standalone" -- although this might not be workable if your project (or related plugins) are setup in such a way that you can't reliably test in Editor like this.

For next steps if the above doesn't work:

1. if your target platform is Android and you're still getting the warning message, feel free to [file a bug report](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) as it's not expected behaviour. Link this answer if you need to for context.
2. if you *need* to have your platform set to iOS when developing on Windows, file a [feature request at the same site](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues). Try to explain why you need this so the team has good context for prioritization.
3. if you want to reach out but not expose the game/team you're working on, reach out via [this support form](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report). It might take a little longer to get to the engineers, but it's way more private than posting on GitHub.

Comment: Got it. Very helpful, thanks! I am, in fact, developing a mobile game (for both Android and iOS) on Windows. I only use my much-less-powerful MacBook Air to build Unity's Xcode project export. So yes, it would be beneficial to not see that error while developing. I'll put in a feature request. Thanks again!